# project-tracking tools for navigating with topic maps?

Tags: project-management, visualization, topic-maps

I'm having trouble with project management & am looking for a good tool that will be a good match for the way my brain works (very associatively). I'd like a bug-tracker but one that I can group tasks into topics and associate the topics to each other in a graph (see the Wikipedia entry on [Topic Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_Maps) ) so that I can find & visualize easily the "big picture". I've tried using AbstractSpoon's [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/) and it works well but it's hierarchical and after about 30 or 40 entries I get lost in a maze of things to do.

any suggestions?

---

**edit:** I've now tried [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net), [Conzilla](http://www.conzilla.org), [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/), and [VUE](http://vue.tufts.edu/). Freemind and Conzilla were a little flaky. XMind seems to be the most polished of the four; they have a "pro" version which is non-free (pay by the month >:( which is weird) but an open-source base version which is free. You can't export the data directly from the program with the free version, but the storage format is just a .jar-style (ZIP file w/ extension .xmind) file that contains a "contents.xml" that is easily parsed if I needed to.

@codeslave:

> but how important is the visual
>   representation any way

Visualization is everything! I've got information overload and I need to be able to navigate a mess of information. I don't want it to be super-Powerpoint-polished, but I need to be able to use the associations that I create to remind myself how to find what I'm looking for. In an ideal world you could just full-text search everything, but that only works if you can remember the search phrase. Often I'll file something under "algorithm" and when I go to look for it I look under "programming" instead, or vice-versa. Associativity solves that problem by allowing me to visually browse my "mental model" of the information I've stored.

Answer (score 4):

You can always get an CVS export from your "favourite" tool and create Topic Maps maps you can view with the Omnigator or the xSiteable tool. I used to have a few XSLT files to do such a job dealing with JIRA data. If the interest is high enough, maybe a ressurection is needed?

Comment: omnigator: sounds interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a small utility that will [import MindMaps into Project plans](http://www.mobiusdevelopment.com/dev/Download.asp?ArticleID=5765697756647927831). Let me know if something like this is helpful and I will develop it further.

Right now I just use it one-way from [MindMap](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) -> Project file. I generally use this for brainstorming and scope management, then export to Project when we like the scope of what we are working with for more formal project management.

Answer (score 0):

What about using good old FogBugz? You can associate cases together pretty easily. You don't get the pretty graph of the topic space/mind map (feature idea Joel) but how important is the visual representation any way.